# Permutations preserve some relative positions

Tags: pigeonhole-principle, combinatorial-proofs

While reviewing some Olympiad training material I was stumped by this question.

> Twenty people sit around a circular table for a discussion. After a
> break they again sit around the table, but in a different order. Prove
> that there are at least two people such that the number of
> participants sitting between them before and after the break is the
> same.

I cannot decide whether this is a combinatorics or pigeon hole question.

The phrase "number of participants sitting between them" is ambiguous to me, but I think it means that any permutation preserves the relative position of some elements.

I played around with this by hand and still cannot come up with a permutation in which this is not the case.

Comment: Not sure I see the point of trying to distinguish between "combinatorics" and "pigeon hole".  I'd argue that the latter is an instance of the former.  As to the problem itself, I'd suggest starting with a number $<20$ to get a sense.

Comment: Having seen the answer, I'd say this is neither combinatorics nor pigeon hole. For me the approach is to identify some characteristic equation about the setup and then try to reach a contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In other words, you want to prove that you can rotate the new seating position such that at least two people sit in their original position.

Label the chairs $1$ to $20$ clockwise. Say that person #$i$ sat in chair #$x_{i}$ before and in chair #$y_{i}$ after. This person will sit in his/her original position after $y_{i}-x_{i}$ rotation clockwise so all you need to prove is that not all $y_{i}-x_{i}$ are unique.

Hint: $\sum{x_{i}}$ equals $\sum{y_{i}}$ in modulo $20$

Comment: So $\sum x_i \equiv \sum y_i \equiv 10 (\textrm{mod} 20)$ therefore
$\sum (y_i - x_i) \equiv 0 (\textrm{mod} 20)$.

But for each of $y_i - x_i$ to be unique, it must span all from $0$ to $19$
which demands $\sum (y_i - x_i) \equiv 10 (\textrm{mod} 20)$, a contradiction.

So is it a corollary that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} i \equiv 0 (\textrm{mod} n)$ when $n$ is odd
and $\sum_{i=1}^{n} i \equiv \frac{n}{2} (\textrm{mod} n)$ when $n$ is even?

My trial on small $n=7$ produces a permutation $1526374$ which preserves no relative positions. The math checks out.